# How to return mongodb Error from extjson::de::Error

Tags: mongodb, rust, actix-web

I have a function, which inserts new records to the database and updates another collection.

```
pub async fn create_post(
    &self,
    new_post: Post,
    user_repo: &UserRepo,
) -> Result<InsertOneResult, Error> {
    let new_doc = Post {
        id: None,
        title: new_post.title,
        content: new_post.content,
    };
    let post = self
        .col
        .insert_one(new_doc, None)
        .await
        .ok()
        .expect("Error creating user");
    let obj_id = ObjectId::parse_str("651551c49a4e27e2e319fb19").unwrap();
    let filter = doc! {"_id": obj_id};
    let user = user_repo.col.find_one(filter, None).await.unwrap();
    match user {
        Some(_) => {
            let id = &post.inserted_id;
            let new_doc = doc! {"$push": {"posts": id}};
            user_repo
                .col
                .update_one(doc! {"_id": obj_id}, new_doc, None)
                .await
                .ok()
                .expect("Error updating user");
        }
        None => return Err(Error::from("User not found")),
    }
    Ok(post)
}
```

I need to return an error from this line if the user is not found `None => return Err(Error::from("User not found"))`.
According to the docs Error is an `enum` that has the following constructor

```
pub enum Error {
    /// Errors that can occur during OID construction and generation from the input data.
    InvalidObjectId(oid::Error),

    /// A general error encountered during deserialization.
    /// See: <https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.Error.html>
    DeserializationError { message: String },
}
```

Now I get the following error

> the trait bound `mongodb::bson::extjson::de::Error: std::convert::From<&str>` is not satisfied with the following other types
> implement trait `std::convert::From<T>`

How can I return a proper error from this function?

Comment: `return Err(Error::DeserializationError{ message:"User not found".to_string()}))` maybe?